# Update the parent case when the child case is closed only on certain recortypes

Tags: apex, trigger, case, update, after

I am trying to update the parent case status when the child case is closed and thhis should happen only on certain record types. Also I need to bring in the last case comment from the child case that is closed and add it as the private comment on the parent case. Below what I Tried

```
public static void setParentStatusOnTISCase(List<case> newCaseRecords){ 
    if(checkRecursiveTrigger.setCaseStatus == false)
        {
            checkRecursiveTrigger.setCaseStatus = true;
            ID recordTypeTGS                = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('TGS').getRecordTypeId();
            ID recordTypeTIS                = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('TIS').getRecordTypeId();
            ID recordTypeTISClosed          = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('TIS - Closed').getRecordTypeId();
            
            set<Id> tisrectypes = new set<Id>();
            tisrectypes.add(recordTypeTIS);
            tisrectypes.add(recordTypeTISClosed);
            
            Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>(); 
            List<Case> csChildList = new List<Case>();
            List<Case> csUpdateList = new List<Case>();
            
            for(Case newCase : newCaseRecords)
            {
                if(newCase.RecordTypeId == recordTypeTGS && newCase.ParentId != null && newCase.Status == 'Closed')
                {
                    parentIds.add(newCase.ParentId);
                    csChildList.add(newCase);
                }
            }        

            List<Case> csList = new List<Case>([Select Id, Status, ParentId,( Select CommentBody From CaseComments order by LastModifiedDate DESC  LIMIT 1) From Case Where ID in :csChildList]);

            if(parentIds.size()>0) {
                List<Case> csParentList = new List<Case>([Select Id, Status,RecordTypeId From Case Where Id In :parentIds and RecordTypeId IN: tisrectypes]);

                for(Case cs: csParentList) {
                    for(Case c: csList) 
                    {
                      if(cs.Status == 'Closed' && c.ParentId == cs.Id )
                        {
                            cs.Status = 'Reopened';
                            cs.RecordTypeId = recordTypeTIS;
                            
                            //commentBody = c.CommentBody ;
                            CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = c.CommentBody, IsPublished = false);
                            insert cc;   
                            
                            csUpdateList.add(cs);
                        }                
                        else if ((cs.Status != 'Closed' ||cs.Status != 'Closed as Duplicate') && c.ParentId == cs.Id )
                        {
                            cs.Status = 'Activity';
                            
                            //commentBody = c.CommentBody ;
                            CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = c.CommentBody, IsPublished = false);
                            insert cc;   
                            
                            csUpdateList.add(cs);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(csUpdateList.size()>0) {
                update csUpdateList;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the main idea is when the case of type TGS is updated with status Closed, only then I want to only update the parent case status if its type is TIS. And also bring the latest case comment from the child case to the parent case. But I am getting error saying `Variable does not exist: CommentBody` wherI am trying `commentBody = c.CommentBody` . Am I approaching the solution right for my uses case or am I missing something here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please don't edit the content of an answer into your original question - this makes it harder for other readers to understand the original problem. You're welcome to add new information, of course.

Comment: @DavidReed Sorry do you want me to add the updated code seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex always requires that you declare variables you wish to use. The variable `commentBody` is not declared, so you cannot assign to it here:

```
commentBody = c.CommentBody ;
CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = commentBody, IsPublished = false);
```

However, you really do not need a temporary variable here. Simply pass the value directly to the `CaseComment` constructor:

```
CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(
    ParentId = cs.Id,
    CommentBody = c.CommentBody,
    IsPublished = false
);
```

### Edit

I didn't initially notice there's a second issue. `c` is of type `Case` and has no `CommentBody` property. You need to access the first Comment you've queried on that Case:

```
String commentBody;

if (c.CaseComments.size() > 0) {
    commentBody = c.CaseComments[0].CommentBody;
} else {
    commentBody = 'YOUR DEFAULT HERE';
}

CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(
    ParentId = cs.Id,
    CommentBody = commentBody,
    IsPublished = false
);
```

There are some other issues here around bulkification and performance.  Instead of doing this "matrix search" strategy with nested `for` loops:

```
            for(Case cs: csParentList) {
                for(Case c: csList) 
                {
                  if(cs.Status == 'Closed' && c.ParentId == cs.Id )
```

you'll want to process one of your Case lists (probably `csParentList`) into a `Map<Id, Case>`, which is easy to do because a Map constructor takes a List:

```
Map<Id, Case> parentCaseMap = new Map<Id, Case>(csParentList);
```

Then, instead of looping to find a parent Case, just loop over `csList` and get the parent from the Map:

```
if (c.ParentId != null) {
    Case parentCase = parentCaseMap.get(c.ParentId);

    // and so on
```

There are a variety of other tweaks and optimizations that would benefit here, but this is a key one that will keep you from immediately running up against CPU time limits.

Comment: I updated the the code in my question I still get the same error as `Variable does not exist: CommentBody`  on the line `CaseComment cc = new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = c.CommentBody, IsPublished = false);` on both the places. Is my SOQl query is correct? `List<Case> csList = new List<Case>([Select Id, Status, ParentId,( Select CommentBody From CaseComments order by LastModifiedDate DESC  LIMIT 1) From Case Where ID in :csChildList]);`  Am I refering the CommentBody correctly?